# aspectj how to intercept all methods of a RooEntity that start with "find"

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-roo

I am using spring mvc and spring roo for my project. I have a Roo entity as follows:

```
@RooEntity
public class Post {
    ...
    public static Post findPostByUserAndCreateDate(User u, Calendar createDate) {

    }
    ...
}
```

Now, I want to intercept all methods in my project that start with "find" and having class annotated with @RooEntity. I want to write a code around call of this method. So, I need something like this:

```
@Aspect
public class FinderAspect {
    ...
    @Around(...I don't know what to put here....)
    public Object aroundFinders(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        //do something
        Object ret = joinPoint.proceed();
        //do something more
        return ret;
    }
...
}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have never used Roo or Spring, but know a lot about AspectJ. So I hope I can help.

**Dummy annotation imitating Roo:**

```java
package org.springframework.roo.addon.entity;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface RooEntity {}
```

**Non-entity sample class:**

This one should not be matched even though it has a `find*` method, because it is not annotated to be a `@RooEntity`:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class OtherClass {
    public String findLastName(String firstName) { return "Doe"; }
}
```

**Entity class + `main` method:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.springframework.roo.addon.entity.RooEntity;

@RooEntity
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application application = new Application();
        application.doSomething("test");
        application.findSomething("test");
        new OtherClass().findLastName("John");
        application.doSomethingElse();
        application.findSomethingElse(123);
    }

    private String doSomething(String string) { return string + "XX"; }
    private void findSomething(String string) {}
    private int doSomethingElse() { return 11; }
    public boolean findSomethingElse(int number) { return true; }
}
```

**Aspect matching entity methods `find*`:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class FinderAspect {
    @Around("execution(* @org.springframework.roo.addon.entity.RooEntity *..find*(..))")
    public Object aroundFinders(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        // Do something
        Object ret = thisJoinPoint.proceed();
        // Do something else
        return ret;
    }
}
```

**Sample output:**

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.findSomething(String))
execution(boolean de.scrum_master.app.Application.findSomethingElse(int))
```